# Implement dragging multiple selected nodes

Tags: javafx

- I have a class which extends **javafx.scene.Node**, say DraggableNode.
- I have written the event-handlers for dragging for any such *DraggableNode* .

  ```
  Class DraggableNode extends Node
  {
      ...
       onMouseDraggedProperty().set(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
              @Override
              public void handle(MouseEvent event) {
                 offsetX = dragStartPoitionX - event.getSceneX();
                 offsetY = dragStartPoitionY - event.getSceneY();
                 setLayoutX (event.getSceneX());
                 setLayoutY (event.getSceneY());
                   ...
              }
       }
   }
  ```
- This event-handler works fine for dragging this node individually.
- Next, I require to select multiple such "nodes" and, dragging of one of the selected node should change the (x,y) co-ordinates of all the selected nodes by **"offsetX"** & **"offsetY"**.
- Selection algorithm is also implemented(in a Class extending **Pane** in which these nodes are added as **children**). But, what I need is to somehow *trigger* the drag event handlers of the other selected nodes so that the final output would look like a multi-drag.

Answer (score 8):

First you create a selection model, say a Set<Node>. Whenever you add a Node to your selection, you add it to the selection model.

When you drag a node, you simply change the position of all of the other nodes of the selection model in your event handler as well.

As simple as that.

Here's code which also supports rubberband selection, shift & ctrl keypress during selection, etc:

*NodeSelection.java*

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Set;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;
import javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.layout.Region;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.Rectangle;
import javafx.scene.shape.StrokeLineCap;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class NodeSelection extends Application {

    public static Image image = new Image("http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/4/41/Siberischer_tiger_de_edit02.jpg/320px-Siberischer_tiger_de_edit02.jpg");
//  public Image image = new Image( getClass().getResource( "tiger.jpg").toExternalForm());

    SelectionModel selectionModel = new SelectionModel();

    DragMouseGestures dragMouseGestures = new DragMouseGestures();

    static Random rnd = new Random();

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

        Pane pane = new Pane();
        pane.setStyle("-fx-background-color:white");

        new RubberBandSelection( pane);

        double width = 200;
        double height = 160;

        double padding = 20;
        for( int row=0; row < 4; row++) {
            for( int col=0; col < 4; col++) {

                Selectable selectable = new Selectable( width, height);
                selectable.relocate( padding * (col+1) + width * col, padding * (row + 1) + height * row);

                pane.getChildren().add(selectable);

                dragMouseGestures.makeDraggable(selectable);

            }
        }

        Label infoLabel = new Label( "Drag on scene for Rubberband Selection. Shift+Click to add to selection, CTRL+Click to toggle selection. Drag selected nodes for multi-dragging.");
        pane.getChildren().add( infoLabel);

        Scene scene = new Scene( pane, 1600, 900);
        scene.getStylesheets().add( getClass().getResource("application.css").toExternalForm());

        primaryStage.setScene( scene);
        primaryStage.show();        



    }

    private class Selectable extends Region {

        ImageView view;

        public Selectable( double width, double height) {

            view = new ImageView( image);
            view.setFitWidth(width);
            view.setFitHeight(height);

            getChildren().add( view);

            this.setPrefSize(width, height);
        }

    }

    private class SelectionModel {

        Set<Node> selection = new HashSet<>();

        public void add( Node node) {

            if( !node.getStyleClass().contains("highlight")) {
                node.getStyleClass().add( "highlight");
            }

            selection.add( node);
        }

        public void remove( Node node) {
            node.getStyleClass().remove( "highlight");
            selection.remove( node);
        }

        public void clear() {

            while( !selection.isEmpty()) {
                remove( selection.iterator().next());
            }

        }

        public boolean contains( Node node) {
            return selection.contains(node);
        }

        public int size() {
            return selection.size();
        }

        public void log() {
            System.out.println( "Items in model: " + Arrays.asList( selection.toArray()));
        }

    }

    private class DragMouseGestures {

        final DragContext dragContext = new DragContext();

        private boolean enabled = false;

        public void makeDraggable(final Node node) {

            node.setOnMousePressed(onMousePressedEventHandler);
            node.setOnMouseDragged(onMouseDraggedEventHandler);
            node.setOnMouseReleased(onMouseReleasedEventHandler);

        }

        EventHandler<MouseEvent> onMousePressedEventHandler = new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {

            @Override
            public void handle(MouseEvent event) {

                // don't do anything if the user is in the process of adding to the selection model
                if( event.isControlDown() || event.isShiftDown())
                    return;

                Node node = (Node) event.getSource();

                dragContext.x = node.getTranslateX() - event.getSceneX();
                dragContext.y = node.getTranslateY() - event.getSceneY();

                // clear the model if the current node isn't in the selection => new selection
                if( !selectionModel.contains(node)) {
                    selectionModel.clear();
                    selectionModel.add( node);
                }

                // flag that the mouse released handler should consume the event, so it won't bubble up to the pane which has a rubberband selection mouse released handler
                enabled = true;

                // prevent rubberband selection handler 
                event.consume();
            }
        };

        EventHandler<MouseEvent> onMouseDraggedEventHandler = new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {

            @Override
            public void handle(MouseEvent event) {

                if( !enabled)
                    return;

                // all in selection
                for( Node node: selectionModel.selection) {
                    node.setTranslateX( dragContext.x + event.getSceneX());
                    node.setTranslateY( dragContext.y + event.getSceneY());
                }

            }
        };

        EventHandler<MouseEvent> onMouseReleasedEventHandler = new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {

            @Override
            public void handle(MouseEvent event) {

                // prevent rubberband selection handler 
                if( enabled) {

                    // set node's layout position to current position,remove translate coordinates
                    for( Node node: selectionModel.selection) {
                        fixPosition(node);
                    }

                    enabled = false;

                    event.consume();
                }
            }
        };

        /**
         * Set node's layout position to current position, remove translate coordinates.
         * @param node
         */
        private void fixPosition( Node node) {

            double x = node.getTranslateX();
            double y = node.getTranslateY();

            node.relocate(node.getLayoutX() + x, node.getLayoutY() + y);

            node.setTranslateX(0);
            node.setTranslateY(0);

        }

        class DragContext {

            double x;
            double y;

        }

    }

    private class RubberBandSelection {

        final DragContext dragContext = new DragContext();
        Rectangle rect;

        Pane group;
        boolean enabled = false;

        public RubberBandSelection( Pane group) {

            this.group = group;

            rect = new Rectangle( 0,0,0,0);
            rect.setStroke(Color.BLUE);
            rect.setStrokeWidth(1);
            rect.setStrokeLineCap(StrokeLineCap.ROUND);
            rect.setFill(Color.LIGHTBLUE.deriveColor(0, 1.2, 1, 0.6));

            group.addEventHandler(MouseEvent.MOUSE_PRESSED, onMousePressedEventHandler);
            group.addEventHandler(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DRAGGED, onMouseDraggedEventHandler);
            group.addEventHandler(MouseEvent.MOUSE_RELEASED, onMouseReleasedEventHandler);

        }

        EventHandler<MouseEvent> onMousePressedEventHandler = new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {

            @Override
            public void handle(MouseEvent event) {

                // simple flag to prevent multiple handling of this event or we'd get an exception because rect is already on the scene
                // eg if you drag with left mouse button and while doing that click the right mouse button
                if( enabled)
                    return;

                dragContext.mouseAnchorX = event.getSceneX();
                dragContext.mouseAnchorY = event.getSceneY();

                rect.setX(dragContext.mouseAnchorX);
                rect.setY(dragContext.mouseAnchorY);
                rect.setWidth(0);
                rect.setHeight(0);

                group.getChildren().add( rect);

                event.consume();

                enabled = true;
            }
        };

        EventHandler<MouseEvent> onMouseReleasedEventHandler = new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {

            @Override
            public void handle(MouseEvent event) {

                if( !event.isShiftDown() && !event.isControlDown()) {
                    selectionModel.clear();
                }

                for( Node node: group.getChildren()) {

                    if( node instanceof Selectable) {
                        if( node.getBoundsInParent().intersects( rect.getBoundsInParent())) {

                            if( event.isShiftDown()) {

                                selectionModel.add( node);

                            } else if( event.isControlDown()) {

                                if( selectionModel.contains( node)) {
                                    selectionModel.remove( node);
                                } else {
                                    selectionModel.add( node);
                                }
                            } else {
                                selectionModel.add( node);
                            }

                        }
                    }

                }

                selectionModel.log();

                rect.setX(0);
                rect.setY(0);
                rect.setWidth(0);
                rect.setHeight(0);

                group.getChildren().remove( rect);

                event.consume();

                enabled = false;
            }
        };

        EventHandler<MouseEvent> onMouseDraggedEventHandler = new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {

            @Override
            public void handle(MouseEvent event) {

                double offsetX = event.getSceneX() - dragContext.mouseAnchorX;
                double offsetY = event.getSceneY() - dragContext.mouseAnchorY;

                if( offsetX > 0)
                    rect.setWidth( offsetX);
                else {
                    rect.setX(event.getSceneX());
                    rect.setWidth(dragContext.mouseAnchorX - rect.getX());
                }

                if( offsetY > 0) {
                    rect.setHeight( offsetY);
                } else {
                    rect.setY(event.getSceneY());
                    rect.setHeight(dragContext.mouseAnchorY - rect.getY());
                }

                event.consume();

            }
        };

        private final class DragContext {

            public double mouseAnchorX;
            public double mouseAnchorY;


        }
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

}
```

*application.css*

```
.highlight {
    -fx-effect: dropshadow(three-pass-box, red, 4, 4, 0, 0);
}
```

Screenshot:

[image]