# How to select multiple rows in JavaFX ListView with mouse drag

Tags: listview, javafx

I'm new to JavaFX and I just can't seem to find how to do this.

I have a ListView inside a Vbox that I populate with an ObservableList of Strings. I've set the SelectionMode of the ListView to MULTIPLE and that has allowed me to select multiple items while holding the Ctrl or Shift keys.

I'd like to be able to click on a row and drag the mouse down and select multiple rows but I can't figure out how to do this. I've tried several searches and seem to only find Drag and Drop and that's not what I need.

```
@FXML private ListView availableColumnList;

private ObservableList<String> availableColumns = FXCollections.<String>observableArrayList("One","Two","Three","Four");

availableColumnList.getItems().addAll(availableColumns);

availableColumnList.getSelectionModel().setSelectionMode(SelectionMode.MULTIPLE);
```

Comment: I'm not able to find any built-in API that would allow this. You may need to use a combination of `listView.onMouseDragged()`, `MouseEvent` filters, and calculating node locations to determine which items to select.

Comment: not supported (as @Zephyr already mentioned) - and probably lots of work to implement: the control of selection state by mouse events is handled in CellBehaviorBase, Behavior is internal api, stored in a private final field of xxCellSkin - the options to change such behavior is to tweak the behavior's inputMap (internal api again, plus requires reflective access to the field) or completely write your own skin/behavior stack.

Comment: You may have to try something other than a ListView; https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30481363/implement-dragging-multiple-selected-nodes

Comment: Thanks for everyone's help. If I get this implemented I'll post my solution here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using JavaFX 10+ then you can extend `ListViewSkin` and add the functionality there. The reason you need JavaFX 10 or later is because that's when the `VirtualContainerBase` class, which `ListViewSkin` extends, had the [`getVirtualFlow()`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/12/javafx.controls/javafx/scene/control/skin/VirtualContainerBase.html#getVirtualFlow()) method added. You can then use the animation API, such as an `AnimationTimer`, to scroll the `ListView` via the [`VirtualFlow#scrollPixels(double)`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/12/javafx.controls/javafx/scene/control/skin/VirtualFlow.html#scrollPixels(double)) method.

Below is a *proof-of-concept*. All it does is auto-scroll the `ListView` when the mouse is near the top (or left) or near the bottom (or right) of the `ListView`. When the mouse enters a cell, the item is selected (crudely). If you want to deselect items if you start dragging the mouse in the opposite direction then you need to implement that yourself. Another thing you probably want to implement is stopping the `AnimationTimer` if the `ListView` is hidden or removed from the scene.

***Note:** The below uses a "full press-drag-release" gesture. In other words, there's a mixture of `MouseEvent` handlers and `MouseDragEvent` handlers. The reason for using `MouseDragEvent`s is because they can be delivered to other nodes, not just the original (unlike with a "simple press-drag-release" gesture). Check out [this documentation](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/12/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/input/MouseEvent.html) for more information.*

**Main.java**

```
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import java.util.stream.IntStream;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.ListView;
import javafx.scene.control.SelectionMode;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public final class Main extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        var listView = IntStream.range(0, 1000)
                .mapToObj(Integer::toString)
                .collect(Collectors.collectingAndThen(
                        Collectors.toCollection(FXCollections::observableArrayList),
                        ListView::new
                ));
        // Sets the custom skin. Can also be set via CSS.
        listView.setSkin(new CustomListViewSkin<>(listView));
        listView.getSelectionModel().setSelectionMode(SelectionMode.MULTIPLE);
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(listView, 600, 400));
        primaryStage.show();
    }

}
```

**CustomListViewSkin.java**

```
import javafx.animation.AnimationTimer;
import javafx.geometry.Rectangle2D;
import javafx.scene.control.ListView;
import javafx.scene.control.SelectionMode;
import javafx.scene.control.skin.ListViewSkin;
import javafx.scene.input.MouseDragEvent;
import javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent;

public class CustomListViewSkin<T> extends ListViewSkin<T> {

    private static final double DISTANCE = 10;
    private static final double PERCENTAGE = 0.05;

    private AnimationTimer scrollAnimation = new AnimationTimer() {

        @Override
        public void handle(long now) {
            if (direction == -1) {
                getVirtualFlow().scrollPixels(-DISTANCE);
            } else if (direction == 1) {
                getVirtualFlow().scrollPixels(DISTANCE);
            }
        }

    };

    private Rectangle2D leftUpArea;
    private Rectangle2D rightDownArea;

    private int direction = 0;
    private int anchorIndex = -1;

    public CustomListViewSkin(final ListView<T> control) {
        super(control);
        final var flow = getVirtualFlow();
        final var factory = flow.getCellFactory();

        // decorate the actual cell factory
        flow.setCellFactory(vf -> {
            final var cell = factory.call(flow);

            // handle drag start
            cell.addEventHandler(MouseEvent.DRAG_DETECTED, event -> {
                if (control.getSelectionModel().getSelectionMode() == SelectionMode.MULTIPLE) {
                    event.consume();
                    cell.startFullDrag();
                    anchorIndex = cell.getIndex();
                }
            });

            // handle selecting items when the mouse-drag enters the cell
            cell.addEventHandler(MouseDragEvent.MOUSE_DRAG_ENTERED, event -> {
                event.consume();
                if (event.getGestureSource() != cell) {
                    final var model = control.getSelectionModel();
                    if (anchorIndex < cell.getIndex()) {
                        model.selectRange(anchorIndex, cell.getIndex() + 1);
                    } else {
                        model.selectRange(cell.getIndex(), anchorIndex + 1);
                    }
                }
            });

            return cell;
        });

        // handle the auto-scroll functionality
        flow.addEventHandler(MouseDragEvent.MOUSE_DRAG_OVER, event -> {
            event.consume();
            if (leftUpArea.contains(event.getX(), event.getY())) {
                direction = -1;
                scrollAnimation.start();
            } else if (rightDownArea.contains(event.getX(), event.getY())) {
                direction = 1;
                scrollAnimation.start();
            } else {
                direction = 0;
                scrollAnimation.stop();
            }
        });

        // stop the animation when the mouse exits the flow/list (desired?)
        flow.addEventHandler(MouseDragEvent.MOUSE_DRAG_EXITED, event -> {
            event.consume();
            scrollAnimation.stop();
        });

        // handle stopping the animation and reset the state when the mouse
        // is released. Added to VirtualFlow because it doesn't matter
        // which cell receives the event.
        flow.addEventHandler(MouseEvent.MOUSE_RELEASED, event -> {
            if (anchorIndex != -1) {
                event.consume();
                anchorIndex = -1;
                scrollAnimation.stop();
            }
        });

        updateAutoScrollAreas();
        registerChangeListener(control.orientationProperty(), obs -> updateAutoScrollAreas());
        registerChangeListener(flow.widthProperty(), obs -> updateAutoScrollAreas());
        registerChangeListener(flow.heightProperty(), obs -> updateAutoScrollAreas());
    }

    // computes the regions where the mouse needs to be
    // in order to start auto-scrolling. The regions depend
    // on the orientation of the ListView.
    private void updateAutoScrollAreas() {
        final var flow = getVirtualFlow();
        switch (getSkinnable().getOrientation()) {
            case HORIZONTAL:
                final double width = flow.getWidth() * PERCENTAGE;
                leftUpArea = new Rectangle2D(0, 0, width, flow.getHeight());
                rightDownArea = new Rectangle2D(flow.getWidth() - width, 0, width, flow.getHeight());
                break;
            case VERTICAL:
                final double height = flow.getHeight() * PERCENTAGE;
                leftUpArea = new Rectangle2D(0, 0, flow.getWidth(), height);
                rightDownArea = new Rectangle2D(0, flow.getHeight() - height, flow.getWidth(), height);
                break;
            default:
                throw new AssertionError();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void dispose() {
        unregisterChangeListeners(getSkinnable().orientationProperty());
        unregisterChangeListeners(getVirtualFlow().widthProperty());
        unregisterChangeListeners(getVirtualFlow().heightProperty());
        super.dispose();

        scrollAnimation.stop();
        scrollAnimation = null;
    }
}
```

---

***Note:** As [mentioned by kleopatra](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57366020/how-to-select-multiple-rows-in-javafx-listview-with-mouse-drag#comment101229924_57366020), at least some of this functionality is better suited for the behavior class. However, for simplicity's sake, I decided to only use the existing, public skin class (by extending it). Again, the above is only a proof-of-concept.*

Comment: Thanks so much @Slaw . We are currently on JavaFX 8 but I'll file this away for when we finally upgrade.

Comment: I believe you can do something similar in JavaFX 8. Since that version is pre-modules the internal code is easily accessible (no need for things like `--add-exports`). From looking at the source code, you just need to extend `com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.ListViewSkin` which has a protected `VirtualFlow` field (from its superclass). Instead of `VirtualFlow#scrollPixels(double)`, however, it's `VirtualFlow#adjustPixels(double)`. Note some things are done differently in the skin classes in FX 8 compared to FX 9+.

Comment: Another difference is FX 8 uses `VirtualFlow#setCreateCell` (and the corresponding getter)—no property. Haven't looked in depth, but you may need to change the way you "decorate" the cell factory.